MS Access with VBA: How to make a Field on a Form that adds a new columns to table by lookup?
I need to create a Field that will function as a Lookup Field but that will look up Column Name (instead of cell content, as in the traditional Lookup Field) and add a new Column with the name specified if none exists. How can I do this, if not by inbuilt Fields by using VBA scripts?
I tried a Lookup Field and restructuring the database so that the parameters are all cell content as well. This involved taking the names of the Columns, which are different chemicals, and moving them into cells under a single "Chemical Name" Column. However, this led to a LOT of entries and increased the row count by 10x. This level of complexity makes exporting content more difficult, and though there is likely a way to reformat programmatically in VBA more easily than to create a new Field in VBA, I find that neither of these seems optimal. I am open to suggestions, please help!

It seems you are looking Access from Excel point-of-view. Provide more detail regarding tables and form codes.

You need to read up on database normalisation. Lots of guides out there.

@Gustav I appreciate your input and will pursue this further; for a starting point, would you be able to recommend anything specific within the field (specific layout or guidebook) that might serve well in this effort?

@ShahramAlemzadeh I have imported an Excel table into MS Access, which might not be optimal database normalization, but does afford manipulation flexibility. The form I want to create would be similar to other databases in industry, such as Aspen HYSYS, SuperPro Designer, or many others to query a chemical database.
My Excel spreadsheet grew very large, and as I want to expand the user base, I need to create a form to streamline the process of adding chemicals to the table. MS Access was built for this.

Need to provide example data and desired output as formatted text tables. Or post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide yours for analysis.

Learn terminology. Tables have fields and records, not columns and rows. Field names cannot be dynamic in table or query. If you want to modify table to add fields, that means editing in design mode or with VBA code. A properly designed relational database should not routinely modify table schema.

Normalize data structure then if you want to export data in a "spreadsheet" arrangement, use a CROSSTAB query to pivot the data. Keep in mind there is a limit of 255 fields in table and query.

would be interesting to see the structure of this table / database, as it sounds that this is the point you should work on. Having a new column (field) for each extra product sounds very strange!
